# realloc failing after multiple uses

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char string[10];
    int count = 0;
    int buff = 1;
    int i = 0;
    char **test = malloc(sizeof(char*) * buff);

    while (1) {
        scanf("%s", string);
        count++;
        if (count > buff) {
            buff += buff;
            test = realloc(test, buff);
            test[i] = string;
            i++;
        }
        else {
            test[i] = string;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

This is simply some test code for a larger project im working on suffering from the same issue (hence why buff is so small). I am not sure why but `realloc()` is failing after ~2-3 calls. Any idea?

Comment: obviously i am using strings less than 10 chars and the while loop being nonterminating is solely for debugging

Comment: Aside: all the pointers will point to the same (the last entered) string value.

Comment: @P__J__  you added the remedy as I was typing - I didn't notice the passing comment to it.

Comment: Never assign the return value of `realloc` to the block directly, for it may return `NULL` and all the previous data will be lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 test = realloc(test, buff);
```

you allocate on the first realloc two **bytes**, then three bytes ...., not the space for two, three ... **pointers**

Your program is just one huge **Undefined Behaviour**

```
 test = realloc(test, buff * sizeof(*test));
```

BTW all allocated pointers **will point to the same place** in memory.

`test[i] = string;` does not allocate the space for the string and it does not copy it.

`test[0] == test[1] == test[2] .... ==test[n]` which is the last scanf-ed string

to store all scanfed strings you need to allocate the memory and copy the string

```
test[i] = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
strcpy(test[i], string);
```

Comment: Better practice to write `sizeof(*test)`

Comment: @JasonS If this answer addressed your question, you should [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: additional question: can you not reallocate room for more pointers in a pointer array? i have been trying to add more pointers to the "test" array but it always seems to say that the reallocation cannot take place. Even with the above answer moved into my code